# MSMQ explorer for windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, msmq

Is there a msmq explorer for windows mobile (better if WM 6.5)? 
Please provide me any link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly you are looking for? There are different MSMQ retlated mechanisms in Windows Mobile. For exmample: the windows messages Message Queue that is used to transport Windows Messages like WM_SHOWWINDOW, WM_KEYDOWN and many more. Then there are Message Queues for Power Notifications and others. For the later ones you need to know the name (as in CreateMsgQueue("PowerNotify", ref options);), see for example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Suresh-35251/handling-the-power-off-button-in-pocket-pc-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: @josef. Sorry being this much late to reply. Our WM software has an option to use MSMQ or a memory based queue. I need to know whether the MSMQ is actually created when the application is configured to use it. What I need is a software to view the MSMQs with there names. No need to explore the messages in a particular queue. Thanks for your attention

Comment: AFAIK there is no API to list known MSMQ. I assume you have to try to attch/create the MSMQ in your app and watch for the result code to know if the MSMQ is attached to an existing one. Similar to check for creating a hanlde to a mutex (existing or new one).